# Undefined method `default_ssl_context' for Net::SMTP:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I am getting this error message after I try to send an email message with Devise, through a gmail account

"Undefined method `default_ssl_context' for Net::SMTP:Class"

This is my production.rb environment

```
require 'net/smtp'
require 'tlsmail'
require 'openssl'

OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
Net::SMTP.enable_tls(OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)

ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :address            => 'smtp.gmail.com',
  :port               => 587,
  :tls                => true,
  :domain             => 'gmail.com',
  :authentication     => :plain,
  :user_name          => 'myemail@myemail',
  :password           => 'password'
```

}

Have you seen this error before? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you have:

```
require 'net/smtp'
require 'tlsmail'
require 'openssl'

OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
Net::SMTP.enable_tls(OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)
```

your `production.rb` should look like this:

```
Portal::Application.configure do

config.cache_classes = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false #Turn to true to get error log
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.assets.compress = true
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  #Defined SMTP options
  #SMTP
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'portal.herokuapp.com' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address              => 'smtp.gmail.com',
      :port                 => 587,
      :domain               => 'gmail.com',
      :user_name            => 'email@gmail.com',
      :password             => 'pass',
      :authentication       => 'login',
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
end
```

Comment: Thank you but I get a timeout error; That's why I used the above settings -> Timeout::Error (execution expired):
  tlsmail (0.0.1) lib/net/smtp.rb:454:in `initialize'
  tlsmail (0.0.1) lib/net/smtp.rb:454:in `open'
  tlsmail (0.0.1) lib/net/smtp.rb:454:in `block in do_start'
  tlsmail (0.0.1) lib/net/smtp.rb:454:in `do_start'
  tlsmail (0.0.1) lib/net/smtp.rb:440:in `start'
  mail (2.5.4) lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:112:in `deliver!'

Comment: @Nick_K what happens when you try this setup

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain myself correctly. Here it is: When I try my settings I get "Undefined method `default_ssl_context' for Net::SMTP:Class". When I try your settings, I get a TimeOut error.

Comment: @Nick_K I noticed that your trying to send an email using devise. What email are you trying and when you receive an error is there not any further logs provided like a trace in the console